# EKS kubectl logs <podname> suddenly stop working

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have pods running on eks, and pulling the container logs worked fine couple days ago. but today when i tried to run `kubectl logs podname` i get a tls error.

```
Error from server: Get "https://host:10250/containerLogs/dev/pod-748b649458-bczdq/server": remote error: tls: internal error
```

does anyone know how to fix this? the other answers on stackoverflow seems to suggest deleting the kubenetes cluster and rebuilding it...... is there no better solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could probably due to some firewall rules or security settings that were introduced. I would encourage you to check it along with the following troubleshooting steps -

1. Ensure all EKS nodes are in running state.
2. Restart nodes as required
3. Checking networking configuration and see if other kubectl commands are running.